# Swift nested dictionary with nil

Tags: swift, dictionary

How can I have nil in the middle of nest Swift dictionaries?

```
var d: [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "name": "Rodrigo",
    "number": 1,
    "nil": nil,
    "more": [
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "nil": nil
    ]
]
```

The second `nil` (inside `"more"`) gives me the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having here is that Swift's `Dictionary` is a value type, and therefore doesn't automatically conform to `AnyObject`. The compiler tries to help you out here, and bridge over to `NSDictionary`, which *is* an `AnyObject`, but unfortunately `NSDictionary` can't hold `nil` values, so you're out of luck.

As I see it, you have a couple options:

1. Go the standard Objective-C route and use `NSNull()` instead of `nil` in your nested array.
2. Rethink the structure of your data. Maybe instead of nested dictionaries, with string keys, you can build a `struct PersonData` that holds all the information you need in typed properties (including optionals). You may find that works even better than this approach.

Comment: So basically there is no way? =/  All I wanted was to construct this dictionary through a series of updates throughout my app and (let's say every 5 seconds) turn this dictionary into a JSON and send it over the web to update something in my server. The 5 seconds notifier shouldn't need to know about which data it will be sending over the web, it just knows that it is kinda like a JSON (i.e. a dictionary).

Comment: I could use empty string instead of nil, but that would be semantically wrong, because let's say I have a key in my dictionary that is "user", and that user can either be ["name": "R", "age": 1] or nil.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz: Note that NSJSONSerialization translates a `NSNull()` to a JSON **null**, so that might be a good solution.